# FOS User Bundle get POST Data from Login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to integrate the new Google recaptcha into the FOS User Bundle Login.

I've successfully overwritten the login template and the SecurityController form FOS where the `loginAction()` happens.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't access the send POST Data from the Login Form anywhere in the Controller. I tried it in the `loginAction()` and in the `checkAction()`, neither of them had the POST Data in the request.

So I'm guessing that there's a service, listener or something else that does a redirect or something else so that the POST data get lost.

Where can I access the POST Data that will be send to the server from the Login Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer within my source code after I drank a cup of coffee and rethought the problem.

You can access the Data, that has been sent from the login Form, with a listener that listens on the login event. This is the listener I configured in my services.yml

```
project.LoginListener:
    class: namespace\Listener\LoginListener
    arguments: [@doctrine,@session,@security.context,@project.someService]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method :onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

Within the listener you can easily access the sent data in the paramter bag of the request. The request is accessable through the event that's given within the listener.