# Symfony2, FOSUserBundle login form overrided, but is not working, after submit only refresh page

Tags: forms, symfony

I override FOSUserBundle's SecurityController's renderLogin() function, now it generate form.

`

```
protected function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_check'))
            ->add('email', 'text', array(
                'data' => $data['last_username'],
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('remember_me', 'checkbox', array(
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('Login', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'error' => $data['error'],
    ));
}
```

I override template also:

```
{% extends "BaseBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

But now after submiting nothing happens, only page refresh. What can be wrong?

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/login_check">
<div id="form">
<div class="form-group">                
    <label class="control-label required" for="form_email">Email</label>     <input type="text" id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
<div class="form-group">                
<label class="control-label required" for="form_password">Password</label><input type="password" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="checkbox">                                                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="form_remember_me" name="form[remember_me]" value="1" />Remember me</label>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" id="form_Login" name="form[Login]" class="btn-default btn">Login</button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" class="form-control" value="xj9SE3uBp6BGmGVhwoeiT_GmR_zc8JE2U9Tz78Zn3hg" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should have a look on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555811/fos-user-bundle-get-post-data-from-login